# Return doesn't exit recursive function in javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

I've read the dozen variations on this question, but those answers haven't led me to what must be an obvious mistake.  Why does this always return `false`?  Why do I see `called again` even after a `found it`?  And if I put a `return` in front of the recursive call, why do I never see `found it`?

```
function subResult (object, start, target){
    console.log('called again')
    if (start === target){
      console.log('found it')
      return true
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < object[start].edges.length; i++){
        subResult(object, object[start].edges[i], target)
      }
    }
   return false
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
for (var i = 0; i < object[start].edges.length; i++){
    subResult(object, object[start].edges[i], target)
}
```

to

```
for (var i = 0; i < object[start].edges.length; i++){
    if (subResult(object, object[start].edges[i], target)) {
       return true;
    }
}
```

I.e. when found your done. If not keep going.

Comment: Wow, that was it.  Thanks so much.  So I'm saying something like "if the recursive call returns true, return true"?  I really thought it would be sufficient to do the first `return true` and then return the recursive call (as in Abu Hanifa's answer) but that just resulted in `false` always being returned.